# Replace text string with PHP session variable using PHP or Javascript

Tags: php

I have a string of text that is part of a URL on a PHP page that looks like this:.

```
<a href="http://www.adomain.com/links.php?EmpNo={{EMP_NO}}">LINK</a>
```

I need to replace the {{EMP_NO}} with a session variable I have created `$SESSION['EmpNo']`

The href is populated by a PHP function that queries the database and writes the href links depending on the userid.

```
function get_user_icons($user_id)
{
    $icons = array();
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);

    $sql = "SELECT ic.* "
        . "FROM gbl_empicons AS em "
        . "LEFT JOIN gbl_icons AS ic ON em.IconId = ic.id "
        . "WHERE em.EmpNo = '$user_id' ORDER BY em.IconId";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $icons[] = $row;
    }

    return $icons;
}
```

Later the actual links are written out like this:

```
$icons = get_user_icons($row_WAATKgblqemplisting['EmpNo']); 

    foreach ($icons as $ic)
    {       
echo $ic['url'] . ' ';
    }
```

I've tried to update this function with str_replace with no luck in both locations.

`str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo']);`

This is not working.  I have also tried to use the em.EmpNo to no avail.  What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: How are you getting that string into `$linkString`?

Comment: I'm not, I updated it.  I basically want to replace any instance of {{EMP_NO}} found on the page with the session.

Comment: Dont just hide variables lol, now the str_replace wont work, and will cause people to think that's the issue.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: `str_replace` doesn't search back through all raw output of the page.  Nothing does.  Unless you're using a templating engine of some kind (as can be implied by the `{{placeholder}}` syntax), what you'd need to do is output the value where it's needed.  Like in an answer posted below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580611/328193

Comment: How do you output that link?

Comment: Updated the question to better reflect what is going on.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like an XY Problem, you must be outputting the html from  somewhere. Be it from the database or right at the end before an echo or a view, you will always have somewhere where you can str_replace or worse use buffering. https://3v4l.org/LJR81

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes, I updated the question.  thanks

Comment: I love it when people say it can't be done...this worked in the foreach loop: foreach ($icons as $ic) { echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo'], $ic['url']) . ' '; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($icons as $ic) { 
    echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo'], $ic['url']) . ' '; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a href="http://www.adomain.com/links.php?EmpNo=<?= $_SESSION['EmpNo']; ?>">LINK</a>
```

Comment: That won't work as the href is written out from a database.  I need to manipulate it after it's written

Comment: <?php echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo']); ?> maybe this should help. use it when you are writing the href from the database

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: Then use `str_replace()` on the value you're getting from the database.  *Before* you output it to the page.

Comment: @David I updated the question as that make sense but still need some help.  Please review.

Comment: change this int the foreach loop:

foreach ($icons as $ic)
{       
echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo'], $ic['url']) . ' ';
}

Comment: @AlamDarji  That TOTALLY worked, please write out an Answer for this so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

[That's not how you use `str_replace()`.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)  You forgot the third function argument, the overall string in which you want to search for something and replace it with something else.

So where is that string?  Looks like it's right here:

```
echo $ic['url'] . ' ';
```

That's what you'd replace:

```
echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo'], $ic['url']) . ' ';
```

Wherever you output or otherwise can manipulate the string value that contains this link, that's where you would replace its contents.

Comment: This solved it: foreach loop: foreach ($icons as $ic) { echo str_replace('{{EMP_NO}}', $_SESSION['EmpNo'], $ic['url']) . ' '; }